# Search buddypress groups with querystring in url

Tags: search, buddypress

If you wanted to search groups in buddypress you can simply navigate to (http://sitename/groups/?s=searchstring) But is it possible to pass other parameters to url like orderby=membernumbers&order=ASC or tags= or search exact phrase ... .
So I'm wondering if any of these actions is possible?

1- Sort group search results based on number of members

2- Search groups Only by their Tags... .

3- Search grous based on tags with exact phrases only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in the url, but you can pass other parameters in the groups loop.

There is a `search_terms` parameter in `bp_has_groups()`. 
It also has an `orderby` parameter that accepts `total_member_count` as the property.

Assuming the tag info is stored in group_meta, you can add a meta_query parameter to the `bp_has_groups()`. [More info from the BuddyPress codex](https://codex.buddypress.org/plugindev/group-meta-queries-usage-example/).